# Find picture taken out of memory issue

Tags: vb.net

why is it that I am getting these errors on my code when I try to sort more than 1,000 images.. it works with 5 images perfectly fine though.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

source code

```
   Private Function FindDateTaken(ByVal strPicture As String) As String
        FindDateTaken = Nothing
        Try
            Const DATE_TAKEN As Integer = &H9003
            Dim dateTaken As String = ""
            Using img As Image = Image.FromFile(strPicture)
                If img.PropertyIdList.Contains(DATE_TAKEN) Then
                    Dim pitem As Imaging.PropertyItem = img.GetPropertyItem(DATE_TAKEN)
                    dateTaken = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pitem.Value, 0, pitem.Value.Length)
                End If
            End Using
            Return dateTaken
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblError.Text = ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: You need to manually call the garbage collector about every 50 to 100 images you load in this fashion. What you are doing is loading the image from a file, converting it to an actual image, and then reading just a small bit of data. You will find it far more efficient to read the portions of the image file you need without converting it to an image.

Comment: Following @Adam Zuckerman suggestion, you can read the multimedia properties using Microsoft's Windows API Code Pack Library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure you saw these messagse in Immediate Window probably because by default you have set option Redirect all Output Window text to Immediate Window in Tools - Options... - Debugging - General. That's why when you right-click in Immediate Window, you cannot see any single option to disable messages. It's Output Window text and thus you need to set it in the Output Window. So simply open up Output Window, right-click and un-check the Exception Messages from context menu